# jQuery-Ui dialog does not show as modal using HTMLService

Tags: jquery-ui, google-apps-script

Using HTMLService with jQuery-Ui dialog sample code from http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal
the dialog does not show as modal

** anything I should change to get the expected result?

Thanks, Fausto

Google Apps Script with the following code:

JS code:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dialog-message.html').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Basic modal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fausto,

put this style in your head section and it will work. This happened because JQuery Modal uses position:fixed which is disallowed by Caja. I changed the position to absolute to get the same behaviour.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Basic modal</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

               <style>
                .ui-widget-overlay {
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 0;
                  left: 0;
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                }
                </style>
      <script>


      $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
          height: 140,
          modal: true
        });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
      <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
    </div>
    <p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: that's weird then, I just tried again in different browsers: Chrome/Linux, Chrome/Windows, Firefox/Linux with same results, no modal (I can click and select text behind the dialog, can't you?) -- can you share the /exec link instead of the /dev to try here

Comment: @FaustoR. in my example I could select the text too. But I saw what happened. The Caja sanitization removed the position: fixed from jQuery Modal CSS. What you need to do is add the style and change from fixed to absolute and you will get the same behaviour. I edit the solution.

Comment: I tried the JQuery UI Position example at http://api.jqueryui.com/position/ and the green box that is supposed to follow the mouse is stuck on the top edge of the screen. I suppose this is also something Caja doesn't allow?!